# Why List<SuperClassType> newList = new ArrayList<SubClassType>() violates type safety?

Tags: java, ocpjp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why aren’t Java’s generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit)

I have declared these classes:

```
class Cereal{}
```

And:

```
public class Flakes extends Cereal{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Cereal> newList = new ArrayList<Flakes>();
    }
}
```

But when I try to compile these Java source code, this compilation error appears:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Flakes> to List<Cereal>
```

My question is: Why is not possible that conversion? Is it violating the type safety rule? Or?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because types are rigid unless defined. You want to try below:

```
     List<? extends Cereal> newList = new ArrayList<Flakes>();
```

This means that its list objects extending `Cereal` and thus above statement becomes valid.

Answer (score 2):

**One sentence:** `Polymorphism` does not apply for `generic type arguments`.

but you can use wildcards giving Cereal as a upper bound.

```
List<? extends Cereal> list = new Arraylist<Flakes>();
```

now this list accepts any thing that is a Cereal, but remember you cannot add anything except null.

```
List<? super Flakes> list = new ArrayList<Cereal>();
```

this list accepts any thing that is a Flakes and a super type of Flakes. i.e.. a Cereal and also an java.lang.Object.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ArrayList<Flakes> newList = new ArrayList<Flakes>();
   ArrayList<Cereal> moreGeneralList = newList;
   moreGeneralList.add(new NonFlakeCereal());
```

Of what type is `newList.get(0)`? It would be `Cereal` but not `Flakes`. Yet `newList`'s `get` is supposed to return `Flakes`.